# How to group a list into n number of groups randomly in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Hello i would like to make a group generator in google sheets, i want to create a random generator number. now that itself would be easy using *RANDBETWEEN* but it should distribute the numbers evenly

For example. In column A i have 10 names that i would like to group and i would like to group them into 4 and the numbers assigned would be placed in column B. All 4 groups must have at least 2 members and any 2 of the 4 groups should have 3 members.

Comment: Welcome. Have you considered that using functions like `RANDBETWEEN` the results will change every time that an edit is made to the spreadsheet?

Comment: I am in the process of finishing my script, ranbetween is lacking since it doesnt check the value of the others. The group number must be evenly spread

Comment: There isn't a single function that does what you are looking for but this could be done by using formulas and some manual steps. The alternative is to use a macro or a script. I think that you should [edit] your question to add more details, specially if you would like help with writing a script.

Comment: "a random generator number. ...but it should distribute the numbers evenly" That sounds like a contradiction in terms.